# Collection of QObjects like ListModel

Tags: qt, qml, qobject

I want to create a **list** of `ShortcutItem`s as a `QObject` and add `ShortcutItem`s into that. For example, I have this:

```
#include <QObject>

class ShortcutItem : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString title READ title WRITE setTitle NOTIFY titleChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString action READ action WRITE setAction NOTIFY actionChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString icon READ icon WRITE setIcon NOTIFY iconChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString font READ font WRITE setFont NOTIFY fontChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int size READ size WRITE setSize NOTIFY sizeChanged )
public:
    explicit ShortcutItem(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QString title() const;
    QString action() const;
    QString icon() const;
    QString font() const;
    int size() const;
    void setTitle(const QString &title);
    void setAction(const QString &action);
    void setIcon(const QString &icon);
    void setFont(const QString &font);
    void setSize(const int &size);
private:
    QString _title;
    QString _action;
    QString _icon;
    QString _font;
    int _size;
signals:
    void titleChanged(QString title);
    void actionChanged(QString action);
    void iconChanged(QString icon);
    void fontChanged(QString font);
    void sizeChanged(int size);
public slots:
};
```

which I can use in QML like this:

```
U.Shortcut{
     title: "title"
     icon: "\uf015"
     font: "fontawesome"
     action: "open"
     size: 1
}
```

But I want to create a list of Shortcuts (some thing like ListModel with ListElements inside it) like this:

```
U.Shortcuts {
    U.Shortcut {

    }
    U.Shortcut {

    }
}
```

How can I create this?
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#specifying-default-properties-for-qml-object-types good place to learn more about this

Comment: What do you want to do with your populated `U.Shortcuts`? Why can't you use a `ListModel` defining the shortcuts' info? What about a `list<Action>`?

Comment: @GrecKo i need inheritance and use my own models which is a cpp model so 
 as far as i know i cant use listmodel for that, and about second part i dont know what you mean about List<Action>!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a `QObject` that has `Q_PROPERTY` as `QQmlListProperty<ShortcutItem>` and `DefaultProperty` as `Q_PROPERTY` itself:

**shortcutcollection.h**

```cpp
#ifndef SHORTCUTCOLLECTION_H
#define SHORTCUTCOLLECTION_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVector>
#include <QQmlListProperty>
#include "shortcutitem.h"

class ShortcutCollection: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<ShortcutItem> items READ items)
    Q_CLASSINFO("DefaultProperty", "items")
public:
    ShortcutCollection(QObject *parent=nullptr);
    QQmlListProperty<ShortcutItem> items();
    int itemsCount() const;
    ShortcutItem *item(int) const;
private:
    QList<ShortcutItem*> m_items;
};

#endif // SHORTCUTCOLLECTION_H
```

**shortcutcollection.cpp**

```cpp
#include "shortcutcollection.h"

ShortcutCollection::ShortcutCollection(QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent)
{
}

QQmlListProperty<ShortcutItem> ShortcutCollection::items()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<ShortcutItem>(this, m_items);
}

int ShortcutCollection::itemsCount() const
{
    return m_items.count();
}

ShortcutItem *ShortcutCollection::item(int index) const
{
    return m_items.at(index);
}
```

Then you register it:

```cpp
qmlRegisterType<ShortcutCollection>("FooModule", 1,0, "Shortcuts");
qmlRegisterType<ShortcutItem>("FooModule", 1,0, "Shortcut");
```

***.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import FooModule 1.0 as U
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    U.Shortcuts{
        U.Shortcut{

        }
        U.Shortcut{

        }
    }
}
```

---

The complete example you find [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55586755)

Comment: yeah exactly i was looking for "QQmlListProperty" how can i search for this types , in java and c# searching for list or collection you find those , what is documentation for same thing in Qt and c++

Comment: @MoreMag I do not understand java, c#, but there is an example in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-default-example.html

Comment: ty Great Answer